# How can I remove SUN light/shadow with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, photo-editing, shadows

[image: wall light]

There is this image.
As you can see, top half is brightened by suns light, other half has shadow cast on it.
I would like to make both parts same so it looks like there is no shadow.

Is there any way this can be done in Photoshop ?

Answer (score 32):

- Create a pattern with a square selection from the top part of the
  illuminated wall

[image: pattern]

- Make a selection where the shadow is
- Make a layer and fill it with this pattern
- **Menu Image** > **Adjustments** > **Desaturate**
- Change the blend of this layer, in this example is Hard Light
- Use the same selection to create an **Adjustment Levels Layer** over the original image and increase the highlights and midtones
- Select just the light part of the image inside this selection and create an **Adjustment Curves Layer** to adjust the light colors
- Select just the dark part of the image inside this selection and create another **Adjustment Curves Layer** to adjust the midtones colors
- Make an empty layer and use the **Clone Stamp Tool** to hide the seam

[image: WALL]

**Menu Image** > **Duplicate** > check **Duplicate Merged Layers Only** option and use this new document to make the last retouches

**Result**

[image: Before&after]

[image: WALL]

Comment: Holy smokes thanks sooo much.
Can you btw tell me what did  you use to make this gif ?

Comment: This looks like a good start, but could it be improved further?

Comment: @Picassomon Possibly a screen recorder, like [this](https://www.screentogif.com/).

Comment: @Mast The colour temperature of the (previously) shaded area can be warmed a bit - sunlight in shadow tends to be a bit more blue than direct.

Comment: @J... That's a great idea.

Comment: @Mast the color of the darker areas in middle of the white parts doesn't match, it's yellow-brownish in the sunlit part and gray in the shadowed area, unlike the rest the shadow line is still visible there.  Presumably a similar approach could be done to get the colors matching there.